# Not able to click submit button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have wrote the code

```
import os
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
# options.add_argument("--headless");
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)   
driver.get("https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm")
```

I am trying to click the button with

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('getdata-button').click()
```

But, button is not getting clicked. How to click the "Get Data Button"?

Comment: `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "getdata-button")))` then `driver.find_element_by_class_name('getdata-button').click()` Also, you do not assign WebDriverWait to a variable.

Comment: It says, selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Comment: So, it cannot find the element on the page. Can you find it by the id rather than the class name or some other element?

Comment: I have tried those methods too. Its still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the  below worked for me with `ID`:

```
url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm"
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id('getButton').click()
```

But you need to send something, otherwise you will see JS alert.

[image]

**Update 1 :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'getButton')))
element.click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Its not getting clicked by my chrome at the moment. Is it any chrome issue?

Comment: What is chrome driver version u have ?

Comment: I am using 89.0.4389

Comment: download latest from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=90.0.4430.24/ here it is 90.0.4430.24

Comment: Its working if I click but with automation, button is not getting clicked. I can fill all other values using automation

Comment: This is after update, This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 89
Current browser version is 91.0.4472.77

Comment: I have added new version of chromedriver but still its giving this error. can you g uide

Comment: @sam : Update code under section update 1, try it out ! and launch the browser in maximizing mode

Comment: I shifted to safari and it worked. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until that element is clickable, otherwise Selenium trying to find that element immediately and fails with `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element` exception.
Try this:

```
import os
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
# options.add_argument("--headless");
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 40)   
driver.get("https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.getdata-button'))).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this works:-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@id='getButton']").click()
```